# How to perform "countif" for several rows in data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, countif

I have two data frames, A and B. In B I have two key columns and for each row in B I need to count the number of rows in A matching those keys.

I know how to solve the problem using a for-loop but it's taking forever and i was wondering if there is a smarter way to do it. I am still quite new to R so you'll have to forgive me if I'm missing some obvious solution.

The data frames have the following strucuture. Of course, in reality the data frames are much larger.

```
A <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 2), c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie")) 
colnames(A) <- c("key1", "key2", "value")

B <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 1, 3), NA)
colnames(B) <- c("key1", "key2", "count")
```

I used the following for-loop and got the correct result.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B)) {
  B$count[i] <- sum(A$key1 == B$key1[i] & A$key2 == B$key2[i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

However, the code took a quite while to run and i suspect there is a better way to do this. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same logic as you but without a loop using `mapply`

```
B$count <- mapply(function(x, y) 
      sum(x == A$key1 & y == A$key2, na.rm = TRUE), B$key1, B$key2)

B
#  key1 key2 count
#1    1    2     2
#2    2    1     1
#3    3    3     0
```

Answer (score 4):

An option in `base R` (similar to @Sotos tidyverse option)

```
aggregate(cbind(count = !is.na(value)) ~ key1 + key2, merge(A, B, all = TRUE), sum)
#    key1 key2 count
#1    2    1     1
#2    1    2     2
#3    3    3     0
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B, .(count = sum(!is.na(value))), on = .(key1, key2), by = .EACHI]
#   key1 key2 count
#1:    1    2     2
#2:    2    1     1
#3:    3    3     0
```

Comment: Huh...so no need to convert both frames to data tables before merging? Just one is enough?

Comment: @Sotos Yes,one of them is enough  especially the outer one

Comment: You updated first anyways. I 'll leave it up for people to compare bad `data.table` syntax Vs good one :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using `merge`,

```
library(tidyverse)

A %>% 
 full_join(B, by = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% 
 group_by(key1, key2) %>% 
 summarise(count = sum(!is.na(value)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
> # Groups:   key1 [?]
>    key1  key2 count
>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
> 1     1     2     2
> 2     2     1     1
> 3     3     3     0
> ```

Adding the `data.table` solution for completion,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(A)[setDT(B), on = c('key1', 'key2')][, 
          .(count = sum(!is.na(value))), by = c('key1', 'key2')]

#   key1 key2 count
#1:    1    2     2
#2:    2    1     1
#3:    3    3     0
```